# Asking user for raw_input to open a file, when attempting to run program comes back with mode 'r'

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run the following code:

```
fname = raw_input ('Enter file name:')
fh = open (fname)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith ('X-DSPAM-Confidence:') : continue
    else:
        count = count + 1
        new = fh         #this new = fh is supposed to be fh stripped of the non- x-dspam lines

for line in new:         # this seperates the lines in new and allows `finding the floats on each line`
    numpos = new.find ('0')
    endpos = new.find ('5', numpos)
    num = new[numpos:endpos + 1]
    float (num)
# should now have a list of floats

print num
```

The intention of this code is to prompt the user for a file name, open the file, read through the file, compile all the lines that start with X-DSPAM, and extract the float number on these lines. I am fairly new to coding so I realise I may have committed a number of errors, but currently when I try to run it, after putting in the file name I get the return:

I looked around and I have seen that mode 'r' refers to different file modes in python in relation to how the end of the line is handled. However the code I am trying to run is similar to other code I have formulated and it does not have any non-text files inside, the file being opened is a .txt file. Is it something to do with converting a list of strings line by line to a list of float numbers?

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default mode of handling a file is 'r' - which means 'read', which is what you want. It means the program is going to read the file (as opposed to 'w' - write, or 'a' - append, for example - which would allow you to overwrite the file or append to it, which you don't want in this case).

There are some bugs in your code, which I've tried to indicate in the edited code below.

1. You don't need to assign `new = fh` - you're not grabbing lines and passing them to a new file. Rather, you're checking each line against the 'XDSPAM' criteria and if it's a match, you can proceed to parse out the desired numbers. If not, you ignore it and go to the next line.

With that in mind, you can move all of the code from the `for line in new` to be part of the original `if not ... else` block.

2. How you find the end of the number is also a bit off. You set `endpos` by searching for an occurence of the number 5 - but what I think you want is to find a position 5 characters from the start position (`numpos + 5`).

(There are other ways to parse the line and pull the number, but I'm going to stick with your logic as indicated by your code, so nothing fancy here.)

3. You can convert to float in the same statement where you slice the number from the line (as below). It's acceptable to do:

   num = line[numpos:endpos+1]
   float_num = float(num)

but not necessary. In any event, you want to assign the conversion (`float(num)`) to a variable - just having `float(num)` doesn't allow you to pass the converted value to another statement (including print).

4. You say that you should have 'a list of floats' - the code as corrected below - will give you a display of all the floats, but if you want an actual Python `list`, there are other steps involved. I don't think you wanted a Python list, but just in case:

   ```
   numlist = []    # at the beginning, declare a new, empty list
   ...
   # after converting to float, append number to list
           XDSPAM.append(num)
   print XDSPAMs                       # at end of program, to print full list
   ```

In any event, this edited code works for me with an appropriate file of test data, and outputs the desired float numbers:

```
fname = raw_input ('Enter file name:')

fh = open (fname)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith ('X-DSPAM-Confidence:') : continue
    else:

    # there's no need to create the 'new' variable
    # any lines that meet the criteria can be processed for numbers

        count = count + 1
        numpos = line.find ('0')

    # i think what you want here is to set an endpoint 5 positions to the right
    # but your code was looking for the position of a '5' in the line

        endpos = numpos + 5

    # you can convert to float and slice in the same statement

        num = float(line[numpos:endpos+1])

        print num
```

Comment: Awesome! Works fine after following your suggestions. Thank you for taking the time to help me out Stidgeon.